# How to install multiple groups in one shot with ansible yum module?

Tags: ansible, yum

> Some plugins like, the yum and apt modules can take lists directly to their options, this is more optimal than looping over the task. See each action’s documentation for details, for now here is an example:

```
- name: optimal yum
  yum:
    name: "{{list_of_packages}}"
    state: present

- name: non optimal yum, not only slower but might cause issues with interdependencies
  yum:
    name: "{{item}}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{list_of_packages}}"
```

I was trying to do this

```
- name: Install libvirt
  yum:
    name: '"@Virtualization Hypervisor" "@Virtualization Client"'
```

But it fails saying that `@Virtualization Hypervisor @Virtualization Client` isn't available. Removing the surround single quote or all quotes won't work either. How to approach this?

Currently I'm using the *non-optimal* solution but I would like to install both groups in one shot.

```
- name: Install libvirt
  yum:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  loop:
    - "@Virtualization Hypervisor"
    - "@Virtualization Client"
```

Comment: documentation says: `To operate on several packages this can accept a comma separated list of packages or (as of 2.0) a list of packages.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you are not passing "a list of packages".  You are
passing a single string:

```
- name: Install libvirt
  yum:
    name: '"@Virtualization Hypervisor" "@Virtualization Client"'
```

A list would look something like this:

```
- name: Install libvirt
  yum:
    name: 
      - "@Virtualization Hypervisor" 
      - "@Virtualization Client"
```

Of if you prefer, the following is identical:

```
- name: Install libvirt
  yum:
    name: ["@Virtualization Hypervisor", "@Virtualization Client"]
```